# Function call does not execute its definition

Tags: python, function

I seek advice on a matter relating to this function.

I have tried various editing and indentation on the code, but it is showing the same result.

It shows `NameError: name 'sentence' is not defined` although I have defined it in the function.

The code is:

```
def about (name, age, likes):
  sentence = "Meet {}, he is {} years old and likes {}".format(name,age,likes)
  return sentence

about ("Jack", 23, "programming")
print (sentence)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call function and assign it to an variable:

```
def about(name, age, likes):
    sentence = "Meet {}, he is {} years old and likes {}".format(name,age,likes)
    return sentence
```

Then

```
val = about("Jack", 23, "programming")
print(val)
```

you can also use `sentence` instead of `val` but this will not be the same `sentence` in function scope.

Comment: Thank you man!  It works! Thank you @mehrdad-pedramfar

Answer (score 1):

try this now....

```
def about (name, age, likes):
    sentence = "Meet {}, he is {} years old and likes {}".format(name,age,likes)
    return sentence

print(about('rohit',23,'programming'))
```

`sentense` scope is bounded to `about` function... and trying to print it out of the function scope may not work.

Comment: It also works bro!  A BIG thanks for the help